# Laravel subtract from database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract a value from the database using eloquent models, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is what I have now:

```
     public function store()
{
    $sku = Input::get('sku');
    $quantitysold = Input::get('quantitysold');

    $inventory = Inventory::where('sku', $sku)->decrement('sku', $quantitysold);
    $inventory->save();


    $transaction = new Transaction;
    $transaction->sku = $sku;
    $transaction->quantitysold = $quantitysold;
    $transaction->save();



    return 'Item has been saved';
}
```

When I try it in tinker, I get the following:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function save() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `save` after using `decrement`.

The `decrement` method itself [runs the query](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1927).